# Quick and easy desktop application for Pivotal Tracker?

Tags: ipad, emulator

I found [a Pivotal Tracker app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pivotal-tracker/id444623375?mt=8) but as you can see, it's an iPad app.

It would be amazing if I could make this app work on my Windows installation using an emulator. Does anyone know how to download the app and run it using an emulator? Alternatively, are there any desktop applications for Pivotal Tracker that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivotal Tracker is available from the [Pivotal Tracker site](http://www.pivotaltracker.com/). As far as I understand, this is a browser-based application, and so is universally available and not limited to the iPad.

There is one free plan and several paid plans, with a 60-days trial period.
The free plan allows up to 5 private projects, 200MB of file storage, and no collaborators.

Comment: Doesn't really answer my question at all.

Comment: First: Is it really the same application as on the iPad? If yes, then it will run for you without an emulator. If not, then my answer is not pertinent and I will delete it.

Comment: I meant specifically, is there an ipad app, as in one that runs mostly off the ipad and not via a browser or a browser on the ipad. i want some other medium through which to use the software that is significantly faster than going via the browser

Comment: I don't understand, do you want : (1) to make this run on Windows same as on the iPad, or (2) make it run natively on the iPad and not as it actually does in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Pivotal's [app bazaar](http://www.pivotaltracker.com/community/app-bazaar) lists [Booster](http://booster.railsware.com/) (OSX). I don't love its lack of customizability, but it might work for you. Seems best suited to tracking your own work rather than other folks.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Although this may answer the question, you should give a more detailed description of the linked content and explain how it relates to the question. This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page goes is removed or goes offline. For more information, see [this Meta Stack Exchange post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259).